# Wrap function Jquery for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this function in Jquery

```js
function row_content(col1, col2) {
  var divs = col1 + col2;

  for(var n = 0; n < divs.length; n+=2){
   divs.slice(n, n+2).wrapAll('<div class="row-content"></div>');
  }
 }

 var col_2_3 = $('.col_2_3');
 var col_1_3 = $('.col_1_3');

 row_content(col_2_3, col_1_3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='col_2_3'>Test</div>
<div class='col_1_3'>Test</div>

<div class='col_2_3'>Test</div>
<div class='col_1_3'>Test</div>
```

I want, with this function to wrap two divs in `.row-content` but it does not work.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is

```
var divs = col1 + col2;
```

Where `col1,col2` are jQuery objects. The above line concatenates the inputs and *Does not* combine the selectors. So `length` wont work as you wish to.

Use jQuery **[`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/)**

```
var divs = col1.add(col2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7w6by7Lz/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.col_2_3, .col_1_3').wrapAll("<div class='row-content' />");
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/5kcr44pv/

UPDATE:  OP forgot to mention there were multiple `cols`

Below works as long as there are equal number of both classes and they alternate.

```
var cols_2_3 = $('.col_2_3');
var cols_1_3 = $('.col_1_3');

cols_2_3.each(function (index, el) {
    $($(cols_2_3[index]).add(cols_1_3[index])).wrapAll("<div class='row-content' />");
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/5kcr44pv/1/

Comment: I forgot, there are multiple col_1_3 & col_2_3. I edited my code

Answer (score 0):

```
var wrapper = $('<div class="row-content"></div>');
$('.col_2_3, .col_1_3').wrapAll(wrapper);
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xznj6Lst/)